# 'bundle install' is creating ./rails folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm running a Rails 3.0.3 app using RVM (Ruby 1.8.7). When I run `bundle install` all the gems install and then I get this message `Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./rails`. But the app isn't recognizing/see those gems. Not sure what I've done wrong that it's doing this. Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet you accidentally ran `bundle install rails` at one point, which configured your bundler to install your gems into the ./rails directory.

To reset that, remove the `./.bundle` directory (or remove the BUNDLE_PATH line from ./.bundle/config). Then `bundle install` will put them in the right spot.

Comment: What if it's still creating a ```/rails``` folder even after I delete the ```./.bundle``` folder?

Comment: third times the charm i guess.